# Modelling in blender without mouse wheel. How to completely move mouse wheel modal functionality to custom keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: modeling, workflow, shortcut

How to edit modelling operator modal\contextual hotkeys?
I'm using blender with a tablet since the beginning. And it doesn't have mouse wheel. I'm really fond of blender shortcut system, and how it is largely utilize buttons under left hand for frequently used commands. But some times you can't go without mouse wheel. In particular with modal hotkeys for adding beveling loop cut and slide and other. For example with beveling 1 to 9 numerical buttons change bevel offset and not segments.

Not only chained to mouse wheel but **M** for offset and **P** for profile[image: Not only chained to mouse wheel but M for offset]
**I want to know how to rebing mouse wheel modal functionality to some buttons.** Stretching hand everytime to page up\down or numpad+- is not an option.
 I was able to rebind proportional editing influence to q\w under left hand with transform modal map in input settings.[image: proportia]

*But there are no other modal hotkeys in input settings. For beveling. loop cut count  etc.*